# Use devise login on another page

Tags: html, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to add a devise login to another page but everytime I hit the submit button it redirects to to the main devise login page. I have tried using `f.submit` along with

```
<%= button_tag(type: 'submit') do %>
  <span>GO</span><i class="fa fa-check"></i>
<% end %>
```

below is the full html

```
<div class="box">

  <div class="title">LOGIN</div>

  <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

        <div class="input">
            <label for="name">Email</label>
              <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email", name: "name", id: "name"%>
            <span class="spin"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="input">
            <label for="pass">Password</label>
            <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "current-password", name: "pass", id: "pass" %>
            <span class="spin"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="button login">
            <%= button_tag(type: 'submit') do %>
              <span>GO</span><i class="fa fa-check"></i>
            <% end %>
        </div>

        <%- if devise_mapping.recoverable? && controller_name != 'passwords' && controller_name != 'registrations' %>
          <%= link_to "Forgot your password?", new_password_path(resource_name), class: "pass-forgot" %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource_class 
     User 
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
end
```

The signup works fine but if a error is present it also redirects to the devise page. I have followed a couple tutorials on this but can not find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. To solve to issue all I had to do was remove the `name:` from the form fields.